# Import SMS from iPhone into iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have 10 messages in my iPhone.I would ilke to get those messages into my iPhone app.So kindly tell me how to do this.

Thanks and Regards,
Srinu Ambati

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using the official SDK.

Comment: Start by looking at CoreTelephony. Here's an example: http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/code-snippet-send-sms-with-coretelephony-work-in-progress.212070/

Answer (score 0):

For reasons of security and privacy, I think it is not possible to read SMS from iPhone with a third party application. However if you want to save your SMS, it seems that a solution exists with this [tutorial](http://menoob.com/2008/12/04/how-to-save-and-read-your-iphone-text-messages-on-your-computer/)

Answer (score 0):

Apple restricts this behavior because of privacy politics. All messages are stored in `/private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db` file and you can't get access to it without jailbreak.